# How to dynamically add nssliders to view using auto layout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsview

I need to add a variable number of NSSliders to a custom view at runtime and I would like to have them spaced evenly across the available space. I've looked at Apple docs and seen some examples on 'net and they *none* of them quite illustrate how to do this. I might have one view, I might have four. How can I programmatically express these constraints between an unknown number of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout

Written for iOS, but easy enough to make work for MacOS